# Can Python argparse take its input from a file?

Tags: python

Can my Python script take its arguments from a file, rather than the command line? I don't mind passing the file containing the arguments on the command line.

I am using [argparse](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiaor2D3urKAhVDxxQKHWH7B3oQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fargparse.html&usg=AFQjCNGfxmw2zSSIQ5m3V5GRr0EyRzJsiw&sig2=qXHNypz9R4ruJV3BQHNBRg).

The reason is that I have a very complex argument list. I suppose that I could just wrap the call in a batch file, or another Python script, but I wondered if this is possible and thought that I would ask and maybe learn something.

So, instead of `myScript.py --arg_1=xxx --arg2_=xxx ... --arg_n=xxx`, can I

`myScript.py --file args.txt` where args.txt contains

```
--arg_1=xxx 
--arg_2=xxx 
... 
--arg_n=xxx
```

Comment: You should take a look at [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html).  If you are using Python2, [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell the parser that arguments beginning with certain characters are actually names of files containing more arguments. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars):

```
>>> with open('args.txt', 'w') as fp:
...    fp.write('-f\nbar')
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
>>> parser.add_argument('-f')
>>> parser.parse_args(['-f', 'foo', '@args.txt'])
Namespace(f='bar')
```

The parser reads from `args.txt` and treats each line as a separate argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by taking command line argument as filename and then opening it. 
like

```
file_name=sys.argv[1]
f=open(file_name)
arguments= f.read()
user_input=arguments.split()
user_argument=[]
for i in range():
    user_argument.append(user_input[i])
```

Here you get the list of user argument in the list user_argument. Perheps you will get what you want!